# Keep getting "Authentication Required" pop up when trying to connect to wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

Nearby networks pop up yet any time I try to connect to them I keep getting asked to re-enter the password even though the password is right.

Also, Ubuntu recognizes the PC's adapter, when I type `lshw -C network` the output is the correct wifi card my computer has.

```
Product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
```

Side note: this problem originated in Windows, today I switched my OS to Ubuntu Desktop and the problem still persists.

Comment: *"problem originated in Windows, today I switched my OS to Ubuntu Desktop and the problem still persists."* This suggests that the problem has nothing to do with either OS. If you're being informed that the password is incorrect, it's because whatever you have input does not match the correct password.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't consider that. Thank you